# Split a number based on two percentages of total

Tags: linear-algebra

It's probably an easy question but I dont know the proper search terms for the problem.

Let's say:

- SALES: Jim sold 5 apples, Sam sold 5 apples, Alex sold 90 apples
- INVENTORY: Jim has 10 apples, Sam has 10 apples, Alex has 80 apples

Now I want to divide 50 new apples. Where should they go?

*A fair split would be something like this:*
If you sell more apples you should get more apples, BUT if you already have lots of apples you should get less apples.

To do this I thought about getting the percentage of total for the sales and getting the percentage of total of inventory and combining them to one number that counts up to 100%. HOWEVER inventory should be a negative factor, the more you have the less you get. So dont think this works.

Both factors (SALES and INVENTORY) should have equal say in how the apples get divided and I cant seem to figure out how to divide it. Been stuck on this for some hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want that no salesman will have his inventory empty before the others, given the constant sales rate. Let's say we split apples to them as $j$, $s$, $a$ and their inventory will be empty simultaneously in $N$ periods of time. Then we have the following system:
$$ j+s+a = 50,\\
10+j = 5N,\\
10+s=5N,\\
80+a=90N
$$
Solving the system gives you the following:
$$
j=-2.5,\qquad s=-2.5,\qquad a=55.
$$
So you probably want to give all the apples to Alex and, moreover, pass 2-3 apple from both Jim's and Sam's inventories to Alex. If you cannot do the latter (i.e. the numbers $j,s,a$ should all be positive), you just give all the apples to Alex

Comment: Thanks Vasily. This sounds logical to me, however, it is not possible to relocate the apples between the salesman. How can I solve the system taking into account j,s,a must all be positive? (I need to eventually get this in R)

Comment: You solve the system then if some salesman gets a negative answer, he should be given zero apples. So you discard all those salesmen who will receive nothing and solve the system again. Repeat until all the answers are positive.

Comment: Thanks. Think that answers my question, now to get it work in R. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the ratio of no apples sold to the no of apples remaining for each one  .  Now take ratio of the above mentioned ratios and then divide the apples according to the obtained ratio.
Sol: 
 FOR JIM
 $$  \frac{sales}{apples remaining} = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2} $$
 FOR SAM
    $$ \frac{sales}{apples remaining} = \frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2} $$
FOR ALEX 
 $$   \frac{sales}{apples remaining} = \frac{90}{80} = \frac{9}{8} $$
NOW THE RATIO OF ALL THE $ '  \frac{sales}{apples remaining} ' $
$$  \frac{1}{2} : \frac{1}{2} : \frac{9}{8} $$
$$  1 : 1 : \frac{9}{4} $$

Total parts : $ 1+1+ \frac{9}{4} = \frac{17}{4} $

Now divide the apples according to the ratio :

Jim's Share :
Share = $ \frac{Jim's part}{total} × (total no of apples) $
   $$   = \frac{1}{ \frac{17}{4}} ×50 $$
   $$   = \frac{1×4}{17} ×50 = 11.76 $$
Since apples cannot be in fraction so
 Share of Jim= 11.76 ~ 12
Sam's Share :
Share = $ \frac{Sam's part}{total} × (total no of apples) $
   $$   = \frac{1}{ \frac{17}{4}} ×50 $$
   $$   = \frac{1×4}{17} ×50 = 11.76 $$
Since apples cannot be in fraction so
 Share of Sam= 11.76 ~ 12
Alex's Share :
Share = $ \frac{Alex's part}{total} × (total no of apples) $
   $$   = \frac{ \frac{9}{4}}{ \frac{17}{4}} ×50 $$
   $$   = \frac{9}{17} ×50 = 26.47 $$
Since apples cannot be in fraction so
 Share of Alex= 26.47 ~ 26